# Can we consider formal power series $P(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom{2m}{m} \left[m^l(4t-1)^l+F_l(t) \right]t^m$ as formal group law?

Tags: formal-power-series, formal-groups

Can we consider the formal power series $P(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom{2m}{m} \left[m^l(4t-1)^l+F_l(t) \right]t^m$ as a formal group law in 1 variable ?  Where $l \geq 0$ are integers and $F_l(t)$ are some polynomials in $t$. The first three are $F_1(t)=2t$, $F_2(t)=2t+12t^2$, $F_3(t)=8t^3+20t^2+2t$. It is given that the power series vanishes identically i.e., $P(t)=0 $ for all $t$.

For formal group law $P(0)=0$ must be zero, which obviously satisfies. 
I can not verify it.

Comment: The wikipedia article on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group_law gives a few conditions that define what a formal group law is. Did you check these conditions? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @quarague, yes in wikipadia there is given a $2$ variable formal power series or formal group laws but here it is in single variable $t$ and that is why got stuck. I am thinking to take $t=(x,y)$. Can you check it for $l=0$, whether it satisfies formal group law?

Comment: I am not aware of such a thing as a "formal group law in one variable". Also, I don't understand the definition of $P(t)$, in particular, what are the numbers $l$, do they depend on $m$, or are they a parameter for the entire $P(t)$ (meaning it's rather $P_l(t)$), or what?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, yes $P(t)$ should be $P_l(t)$ actually and $l$ are positive integers

Comment: If $f\in k[[t]], f\equiv bt \bmod (t^2)$ with $b\in k^*$ then $u(t) \mapsto u(f(t))$ is a well-defined injective and surjective endomorphism of $k[[t]]$ thus $f^{-1}\in k[[t]]$ and $F(x,y)= f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))\in k[[x,y]]$ is an (abelian) formal group law (and $u \oplus v = F(u,v)$ is an abelian group law on $t k[[t]]$) @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: @reuns, Can you look at this question and comment please-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404245/how-to-associate-bernouli-numbers-or-bernouli-polynomials-into-the-relation-s

Comment: @reuns: Thanks, I was vaguely aware of that construction, but I did not think it was meant here. Well but if that's the interpretation, most of the formula is clutter and we only check the zero-th coefficient is $0$ and the first is not (which e.g. has nothing to do with the $F_l$'s except that their constant term is $0$).